# Wrong scaling in plot

Tags: plot, pine-script

With only one plot, the scaling is correct, i.e. between [0,100]:

[image]

When I use more than 1 plot, the scaling is wrong:

[image]

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", overlay=false)

src  = input(close, title="Index Source")
v1 = security("OANDA:EURUSD", timeframe.period, src)
v2 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, src)
v3 = security("OANDA:GBPUSD", timeframe.period, src)

Length = input (8, minval=1, title = "Stochastic Length")
k = input (3, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %K")
StoV1 = stoch (v1, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
StoV2 = stoch (v2, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
StoV3 = stoch (v3, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
Kv1 = sma (StoV1, k)
Kv2 = sma (StoV2, k)
Kv3 = sma (StoV3, k)
plot (Kv1, title  ="%K", color = color.black, linewidth=2)
plot (Kv2, title  ="%K", color = color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot (Kv3, title  ="%K", color = color.red, linewidth=2)
```

Any ideas as how to fix this?

Comment: Just a FYI, your code after your edit does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with how many plots you have. It depends on the chart you are on. When you are on a chart with high values (BTC), your values seem to be in the millions. When you are on a chart with low values (EURUSD), your values are not that high.

I found that weird because your plot values should not change depending on the chart you are on. After playing around a little, I found a mistake in your code.

```
StoV1 = stoch (v1, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
StoV2 = stoch (v2, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
StoV3 = stoch (v3, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
```

According to the documentation, when you use `highest()` and `lowest()` with one parameter, it will use `high`/`low` as a source to the function.

> One arg version: x is a length. Algorithm uses high as a source
> series.

However, that `high`/`low` belongs to the chart you are on. Hence, your plot values differ when you change the pair.

What you need to do is, use `security()` to retrieve `high` and `low` values from the pairs you want to analyze and use those values in your calculations.

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", overlay=false)

src  = input(close, title="Index Source")
v1 = security("OANDA:EURUSD", timeframe.period, src)
v2 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, src)
v3 = security("OANDA:GBPUSD", timeframe.period, src)

h1 = security("OANDA:EURUSD", timeframe.period, high)
h2 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, high)
h3 = security("OANDA:GBPUSD", timeframe.period, high)

l1 = security("OANDA:EURUSD", timeframe.period, low)
l2 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, low)
l3 = security("OANDA:GBPUSD", timeframe.period, low)

Length = input (8, minval=1, title = "Stochastic Length")
k = input (3, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %K")
StoV1 = stoch (v1, highest(h1, Length), lowest(l1, Length), Length)
StoV2 = stoch (v2, highest(h2, Length), lowest(l2, Length), Length)
StoV3 = stoch (v3, highest(h3, Length), lowest(l3, Length), Length)
Kv1 = sma (StoV1, k)
Kv2 = sma (StoV2, k)
Kv3 = sma (StoV3, k)
plot (Kv1, title  ="%K", color = color.black, linewidth=2)
plot (Kv2, title  ="%K", color = color.blue, linewidth=2)
plot (Kv3, title  ="%K", color = color.red, linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Change the pair of your chart and you will see that your values are consistent. Scaling seems to be okay too.

Comment: Even though I accepted your answer, I think there is a discrepancy between the built-in stoch values and the ones that this script finds, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70026059/built-in-stochastic8-3-3-computes-different-than-the-one-i-coded-in-pine

Answer (score 0):

It scales by the biggest value in the chart, blue plot is valued in millions, while red in thousands and black is just decimals.

Comment: All datasets, if plotted individually, are shown correct with values between [0,100] which should be the case because it's a "stochastic computation". But when they are shown on the same plot, then one of them instead of the "stochastic computation" just shows the FX price value. No?

Comment: Why would the colors in themselves distinquish between millions, thousands and decimals?