# Built-in stochastic(8,3,3) computes different than the one I coded in Pine

Tags: plot, pine-script, stochastic

Built-in Stoch vs test:

[image]

It looks as if another smoothing perhaps is applied. Same settings:

[image]
[image]

Notice I use (8,3,3) and that D is actually not used or plotted here.

Is the functions, built-in and the one I use, not WYSIWYG?

Built-in:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
periodK = input.int(8, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(3, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, periodD)
plot(k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```

Mine:

```
//@version=4
study(title="test", overlay=false)

src  = input(close, title="Index Source")
v2 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, src)
h2 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, high)
l2 = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, low)

Length = input (8, minval=1, title = "Stochastic Length")
k = input (3, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %K")
StoV2 = stoch (v2, highest(h2, Length), lowest(l2, Length), Length)
Kv2 = sma (StoV2, k)
plot (Kv2, title  ="%K", color = color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Remember to use USDJPY for comparison!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're different because your code does something different than the built in's code. The result differs because you're using highest() and lowest() in the stoch() call. They aren't needed if you're trying to reproduce the built in function. The stoch() function performs the equivalent of highest/lowest already in it's process, so what you have is the equivalent of doing highest(highest()). Also you can reduce the number of security calls by performing the operation within one security call like so :

```
stoch_k = security("OANDA:USDJPY", timeframe.period, sma(stoch(src, high, low, Length), k))
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution, thank you, and it is very similar to the built-in function, but the built-in function is less smooth/has less interpolation, even though they have the same smoothing parameter (in my case k=3). Any ideas as to why this is the case, and more importantly, how can I "fix" this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, they produce identical results for me when both are using the same 8/3/3 values : https://www.tradingview.com/x/qaba8ivJ/

Comment: I have just checked again, and the k-values are identical. Here is a screen dump: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EURAUD/NluxzC6q-divergence/

Comment: This is the script for comparison: https://www.tradingview.com/script/WL3IKtSg-StoRKTstrengthH1v2/

Comment: You don't need the extra sma smoothing for `Kv1`. It's already being done inside the security call. `v1` is now all you need for the correct calc for stoch k

Comment: Now I understand, thank you!!!